# Check if a string is too big to fit in a TextView

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, textview

I have an `EditText`, a `TextView` and a `Button`. I want to check whether the string from `EditText` is too big or not to fit the `TextView`, if not I want to append `"..."` to the string, so if I write "That's a nice coat" and that's too big to fit in the `TextView` it shows "That's a ni...". I can't add more lines to the `TextView` to make it fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use maxLines=1 and ellipsize=end in your TextView

if in code, use `mText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)`

Comment: I believe that the option singleLine=true make things more clear, but both will work.

Comment: singleLine is deprecated now. Instead use maxLines=(any no. of lines)

Comment: I always use both singleLine=true and lines=1 in this case.

Comment: molte grazie kind sir

Comment: @Kurlicue only english, please